# For some reason I can't update my Mac OS X 10.7.4 to the latest software?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I've been wanting to update my mac for a long time but for some reason it won't let me whenever I try.

I'm not an expert when it comes to computers so maybe I'm doing something wrong but if anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated!

I'm using a Macbook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Here's a photo that might help? If you need more information please tell me.

[image: Problem]

Comment: What do you consider to be "Latest software"? The updates haven't been called 'Mac OS X Update' for quite some time, so I'm guessing you are trying to install 10.7.5. Try downloading the 10.7.5 Combo Updater from here - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582

Comment: I just want to be able to update my mac to at least 10.8 or over.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no "at least" with Apple OS updates - there is 10.7.5 or 10.11.0. You can go up to the latest version of your current OS, which is what that error message looks like, or you can get the latest OS from the App Store application, which these days will require an Apple ID. You can't get anything in between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, what's happening is your download is corrupted so when OS X does its integrity check, its' failing it. This is the message you are seeing.

It would be **very** helpful if you could post exactly which computer you are using, specifically the Model Identifier:, e.g MacBookPro10,1 and or MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013). If your computer can run the newest software (El Capitan), then you just need to open the mac app store, hit 'Get' and follow the steps on the screen. **El Capitan is a free upgrade!**

If your computer is too old to upgrade past 10.7 (Lion), you have some options as well:

- Download the standalone updater: [OS X Lion Update 10.7.5 (Client Combo)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582?locale=en_US)
- Reboot, and try again a few times. Sometimes it gets through
- Try from a friend's house who uses a different ISP. I've seen this happen when an ISP's CDN caches a corrupted copy.

Hopefully you can just upgrade to El Capitan and skip this whole thing.

Comment: It seems that I'm using a Macbook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) if that'll help!

Comment: It's been a little while - but anyway your macbook air should be compatible with the latest OS update. Did you have any luck upgrading to El Capitan?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but on certain systems like my Mac Pro 2,1 it will not upgrade to 64bit OS and this is the first hang up I have found trying to upgrade iTunes which leads me to this upgrade for some reason